# Saving a cycling number with localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've been trying to find an answer to this all morning and can't seem to get it right.

The idea is to have a different array item display when the user clicks the button. The problem is that once they go to a different page, the array resets back to 0 and starts over. I want it to remember where it is in the array and be able to continue even if the user has gone to a different page.

This is what I have so far, but it will break if I switch to a different page before clicking on the button.

```
function iAmCarousel() {
    var describe = document.getElementById("describe");
    var describeArray = [];
        describeArray[0] = "Front End Web Developer";
        describeArray[1] = "Responsive Design nut";
        describeArray[2] = "Photoshop nerd";
        describeArray[3] = "soon to be husband";
    var refreshButton = document.getElementById("refresh");
    var index = localStorage.getItem("Index");

    describe.innerText = describeArray[index];

    refreshButton.onclick = function() {
        while(index < describeArray.length) {
            index++;
            localStorage.setItem("Index", index);
            if(index == describeArray.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            describe.innerText = describeArray[index];
            break;
        }
    }
}
iAmCarousel();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "Index" will not be set in `localStorage`, and calling `getIndex()` on a non-existant key returns `null`. You're left with `describeArray[null]`, which won't work (and will give you `undefined`).

```
var index = localStorage.getItem("Index");

if (index === null) {
    index = 0;
}

describe.innerText = describeArray[index];
```

... or you can just do `var index = localStorage.getItem("Index") || 0;` (via [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation))

Comment: The if statement did the trick. I tried the short circuit evaluation, but it did the same thing. Thank you sir.